# Xcode - storyboard - UIPickerView - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard, uipickerview, exc-bad-access

I am using UIPickerView with storyboard. When I link the Datasource and delegate of PickerView with my view, the simulator throw an error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). This happens when I try to access the PickerView in my ViewDidLoad to move it to a specific row.

When I remove the datasource and the delegate. The error disappears but I do not see the PickerView anymore.

the simulator goes to main.m at this code and stops

```
    in main)int argc, char *argv[])
{
 @autoreleasepool{
        return UIApplicationMain(argc,argv,nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of an error in one of the methods that sets the title of the columns. I wrote it as `NSInteger` while it should be `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occured to me because I was not keeping the `UIPickerView's` `delegate` and `dataSource` as a property. If you are using `ARC`, make sure that the manager object stays alive and not `auto-released`.